# Does Google serve results that are anchor links?

Tags: google-search

Can a result from Google ever be an anchor link "into" a document, like for example

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Tyre#Early_life

(As opposed to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Tyre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a link within a page or a named anchor can be part of a Google search result's [snippet](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2009/09/jump-to-information-you-want-right-from.html)

If you try this link - https://www.google.com/search?q=trans+fats

..you will notice that the first result (at least at the time I write) is a Wikipedia article which has additional links within the same result pointing to named anchors within that page including this one - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_fat#Presence_in_food

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Probably because anchor links just go to a certain point on a page and Google is interested in the whole document. There is a more in-depth answer in [this article](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/anchor-links.html), which also talks about how AJAX calls with `!#` are handled.